# Hadoop Pig GROUP by id, get owner_id?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

In Hadoop I have many that look like this:
`(item_id,owner_id,counter)` - there could be duplicates but ALWAYS the `item_id` has the same `owner_id`!

I want to get the SUM of the `counter` for each `item_id` so I have the following script:

```
alldata = LOAD '/path/to/data/*' USING D; -- D describes the structure
known_items = FILTER alldata BY owner_id > 0L;
group_by_item = GROUP known_data BY (item_id);
data = FOREACH group_by_item GENERATE group AS item_id, OWNER_ID_COLUMN_SOMEHOW, SUM(known_items.counter) AS items_count;
```

The problem is that in the `FOREACH` if I want to take `known_items.owner_id` - that would be a tuple that has the sum of all grouped `item_id`. What would be the most efficient way to get the first one of the owners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution gives you the right answer if your assumption that each `item_id` has the same `owner_id` is correct, and will let you know if it is not: incude the `owner_id` as part of the group.

```
alldata = LOAD '/path/to/data/*' USING D; -- D describes the structure
known_items = FILTER alldata BY owner_id > 0L;
group_by_item = GROUP known_data BY (item_id, owner_id);
data = FOREACH group_by_item GENERATE FLATTEN(group), SUM(known_items.counter) AS items_count;
```

Comment: It is same for each item_id by definition. Thank you about that solution, I will test it out.

Comment: Same by definition, but you never know if something somewhere gets messed up so that your data does not match your expectations. :)